# Incomplete definition of type "struct objc_method"

Tags: objective-c, ios, runtime, forward-declaration

I'm really confused with this problem. What I need to do is use some obj-c runtime feature in my project. Here is simple code in my .m file:

```
#import "Base.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation Base
- (void)someMethod {
    NSUInteger numberMethods = 0;
    Method *classMethods = class_copyMethodList([self class], &numberMethods);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberMethods; i ++) {
        classMethods[i]->method_name; //incomplete definition of type "struct objc_method"
    }
@end
```

I got the following error: incomplete definition of type "struct objc_method". After some inspecting objc/runtime.h file I found something like this:

some code...

```
typedef struct objc_method *Method;
```

...some code...

```
struct objc_method {
    SEL method_name                                          OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    char *method_types                                       OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
    IMP method_imp                                           OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE;
}
```

Is this something like forward declaration problem, or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Martin answer, you should use functions like `method_getName` to retrieve the name of the method `classMethods[i]`.

This is much more portable (especially these fields in the structure no longer exists since Objective-C 2.0 as the macro suggests) and will avoid problems like the one you have when the Runtime evolves.

Comment: Oh, I love you!:) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

These members cannot be accessed!
OBJC2_UNAVAILABLE macro indicates that a member is not available and only provides some insight into the structure.